# Merge values in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge values in a pandas df. I only want to merge the first and last values in a row. But it has to be preceded by a specific value.

For the df below, if the value in Col A is X, then merge the next and last value.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : ['X','','X',''],
    'B' : ['A Big','No','Foo','No'],           
    'C' : ['No','Merge','Bar','Merge'],
    'D' : ['Cat','Thanks','','Thanks'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Intended Output:

```
   A   B        C          D
0  X           No  A Big Cat
1     No    Merge     Thanks
2  X      Foo Bar           
3     No    Merge     Thanks
```

I have tried

```
if df.A == 'X':
df["Com"] = df["B"].map(str) + df["D"]
```

But it returns a ValueError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
m = df.A == 'X'

def f(x):
    s = x[x!= '']
    x[s.index[-1]] = x[s.index[1]] + ' ' + x[s.index[-1]]
    x[s.index[1]] = ''
    return x

df = df.mask(m, df[m].apply(f, axis=1))
print (df)

   A   B        C          D
0  X           No  A Big Cat
1     No    Merge     Thanks
2  X      Foo Bar           
3     No    Merge     Thanks
```

Comment: I tried this on my actual dataset and i'm getting an error `TypeError: ('must be str, not float', 'occurred at index 81.0')`. It's definitely a string though?

Comment: I think there should be non strings values, so use `df = df.astype(str).mask(m, df[m].apply(f, axis=1))`

Comment: Cheers @jezrael

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterating through the dataframe:

```
for value in df:
    if value == 'X':
        df["Com"] = df["B"].map(str) + df["D"]
print(df)
```

The value error you get is because Pandas cannot check based on the Series, but has to check on the actual row itself.

Comment: thanks @sshah98 but nothing get's merged with this code